# What does this author mean by "limiting frequency" (in the context of frequentist statistics)

Tags: statistics

I am reading *All of Statistics* by Larry Wasserman. On page 176, he says that Bayesan statistics is different than frequentist statistics, in part, because Bayeseans believe that "probability describes degree of belief, not limiting frequency." What does he mean by "limiting frequency" here?

Comment: According to the frequentist's view the probability is a limit of relative frequencies. So, the probability is called limiting frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an experiment where one outcome ("success") has probability $p$.
According to the Strong Law of Large Numbers, if this experiment is repeated indefinitely (and independently),  the ratio (number of successes)/(number of trials) almost surely approaches the limit $p$ as the number of trials goes to $\infty$.  To a "frequentist", this is the definition of the probability of an event.

Comment: perfect. thanks.